# How to use getElementByID inside If statement?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-8

How to use getElementByID inside If statement ?
I have to if check a particular logo appears after running some file on a IE software. I can get the logo using getElementByID. Once getting that i want check if the logo is present. If present, then go ahead, else stop.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's `Nothing`

```
Set myElement = doc.getElementById("my_ID")

If myElement Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Element not found"
    Exit Sub '// Optional
Else
    '// Do something with element
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need some more help. Is there any way to save the ID (of the same element which we recover using getElementById) in some variable like myElement_1 ?

Comment: try `myElement_1 = myElement.Id`

Comment: Thanks! I did these changes. It is working now but there are further requirements for which I need to get an element by ID and then compare its Class (JAVA script class) with a particular pre-defined class. Can I use myElement_1 = myElement.Class